# Why is my instance variable (@reservation.room) nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a reservation system in rails 5.0.1. I have a user, room and reservation model:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :reservations
```

**room.rb**

```
has_many :reservations
```

**reservation.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :room
```

**reservation_controller.rb**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def create
        @reservation = current_user.reservations.create(reservation_params)

        redirect_to @reservation.room, notice: "Your reservation has been created"
    end

    private
        def reservation_params
            params.require(:reservation).permit(:start_date, :end_date, :price, :total, :room_id, :user_id)
        end
end
```

**_form.html.erb (view)**

```
<%= form_for([@room, @room.reservations.new]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :start_date %>
    <%= f.text_field :end_date %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :room_id, value: @room_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :price, value: @room_price %>

    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Book Now", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting this error:

[image]

### Question:

**Why is my @reservation.room nil?**

If I type in the rails console: @reserveration = current_user.reservations.create(reservation_params)
Then I am getting:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for main:Object

If you need further information just let me know!

Comment: Your room_id params is empty. That is causing you your issue.

Comment: Why is my room_id params empty and why I dont get a working redirect? Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised that you don't get the same error in the browser as you do in the console. Your controller hasn't instantiated current_user - did you you remove some code for brevity when posting it in your question?

Comment: Not really... only unnecessary code which has to do with different models for clarity reasons... I am still trying to figure this one out :/

Comment: @henners66: `current_user` is likely set in application controller.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it is not! ;)

Comment: @trickydiddy: in this case, it is done [in the bowels of `devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/ebe65b516b3883005db2b02f49414c411a2f301d/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L86-L137).

Comment: ah i see ... i just checked and indeed it's a helper method of devise.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but you can get current_user setup from rails console by following the instructions at https://gist.github.com/seabre/2855072 - maybe it will help in debugging.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this out! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

The @room variable was missing and then I had to merge it!

**reservation_controller.rb**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def create
        @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
        @reservation = current_user.reservations.create(reservation_params.merge(room_id: @room.id))
        redirect_to @reservation.room, notice: "Your reservation has been created"
    end

    private
        def reservation_params
            params.require(:reservation).permit(:start_date, :end_date, :price, :total, :room_id)
        end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is my instance variable (`@reservation`) nil?

It's not. It is `@reservation.room` that is nil.

Before you ask "why is that then?", inspect your params that you post to the action.

Comment: You are right thanks! I updated my question! I have noticed that the user_id params is not necessary. I have got the :room_id params so I dont know why I get this error...

Comment: What's the value of `params[:room_id]`?

Comment: In this case above it has the value of "2"

Comment: Ah, right, my bad. Your problem is that you need `params[:reservation][:room_id]` (not `params[:room_id]`) and that one is empty. You need to trace back why this happens. (*Hint: it comes from a form. Which is rendered with an empty value.*)

Comment: (*in my original comment I meant to say `reservation_params[:room_id]`*)